# Setting text for external HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set text for a div which is located in external html file, but when I give the ID of that div, it is not recognized, what should I do?
I load the external HTML file like this:

```
$('#header').load("resources/html/header.html");
```

then I try to set "headerTitle" which is inside header.html

```
$('#headerTitle').text($('#buidlingComboBox :selected').text());
```

If I give an ID which is inside main HTML file, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to wait until the content is available, and `load()` has a handy callback for that :

```
$('#header').load("resources/html/header.html", function() {
    $('#headerTitle').text( $('#buidlingComboBox').val() );  
});
```